# Subclassing Mock in Python 2.7

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock, python-unittest.mock

I have a set of unit tests which will repeatedly be using a certain cooperator class `Rental` that I want to mock, with the same arguments passed every time. To make this easier, I want to make a subclass of mock.Mock and pass the arguments on creation. Here's the code:

```
class RentalMock(Mock):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RentalMock, self).__call__(*args, spec_set=Rental, **kwargs)
        self.get_points.return_value=0
        return self
```

The problem is, when I instantiate this class, that override has no visible effect. And trying to override it here *also* doesn't work.

```
> a = RentalMock()
> a.get_points()
<RentalMock name='mock.get_points' id='4447663888'>
> a.get_points.return_value = 0
> a.get_points()
<RentalMock name='mock.get_points' id='4447663888'>
> a.configure_mock(**{"get_points.return_value":0})
> a.get_points()
<RentalMock name='mock.get_points' id='4447663888'>
```

I'm thoroughly confused. I've tried three methods, all taken directly from the docs, and none seem to work. When I pass these arguments directly to an instance of Mock, they work fine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overriding `__call__` when it looks like you want to override `__init__`. Subclassing can often get involved, especially with something as already intricate as Mock.  Perhaps a factory function would be simpler.

Comment: ...yup, I misread the subclassing example I was using. Mock is weird enough that using call instead of init to affect the guts of it seemed plausible